# SharePoint Visual Studio Workflow Only Works The First Time

Tags: software, microsoft-word

Hoping someone has some direction on solving the following issue.

I have a workflow, which changes the name of a SharePoint document based on the selected content type ID.
The workflow is set to run on the creation of a new item.
In this instance clicking New in the document library view creates a Word or Excel document and the first time I do this the workflow works perfectly naming the item with the values that have been obtained from a webservice.

If I now create a second new Word document using the same method the workflow fails.

Comment: It is a long time since I used Sharepoint so my memory is less than perfect.  I believe that at the end of the workflow you need to set some flag to mark it as fully complete.  Only then will Sharepoint start looking for the next new item.

Comment: This question does not seem to be about writing.